# Mongodb Deserialize a nested dictionary with the same type as its parent class

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, deserialization

I have a legacy project, that has mongodb as a database. It uses the C# driver.
the mongodb database has a collection that contains objects with the following structure:

```
    public interface IHtmlCompositeBlock
    {
        [BsonId]
        Guid Id { get; set; }
        string Label { get; set; }
        string Tag { get; set; }
        int BrandId { get; set; }
        int HtmlBlockCount { get; set; }
        IDictionary<int, IHtmlCompositeBlockItem> LocalizedItems { get; set; }      
    }
```

When I want to read items in that collection, I get an error stating that the property **LocalizedItems** cannot be deserialized.

Here is the error message:

> System.FormatException: 'An error occurred while deserializing the LocalizedItems property of class MyProject.HtmlCompositeBlock: Unable to determine actual type of object to deserialize for interface type MyProject.IHtmlCompositeBlockItem.'

The legacy code used an **IDiscriminatorConvention** to handle this deserialization. The driver version back then was 1.9 But this no longer works with the  version 2.3 of the driver, and I get a stackoverflow exception in the IDiscriminatorConvention.

My question is, how can I make mongodb handle smoothly the deserialization of that nested dictionary please ?

```
    public class MyDiscriminator : IDiscriminatorConvention
    {
        static int incr = 0;
        public IDiscriminatorConvention discriminator = new NormAdapterDiscriminatorConvention();

        public IDiscriminatorConvention scalarDiscriminator = new ScalarDiscriminatorConvention("_t");

        public string ElementName
        {
            get { return discriminator.ElementName; }
        }

        public Type GetActualType(IBsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType)
        {
            try
            {
                if (nominalType == typeof(object))
                    return scalarDiscriminator.GetActualType(bsonReader, nominalType);
                
                //NOTE: The process fails here, with a stackoverflow exception after going through this function more than a thousand times 
                var val = discriminator.GetActualType(bsonReader, nominalType);

                return val;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public BsonValue GetDiscriminator(Type nominalType, Type actualType)
        {
            return discriminator.GetDiscriminator(nominalType, actualType);
        }
    }

    public class NormAdapterDiscriminatorConvention : StandardDiscriminatorConvention
    {
        const string elementName = "__type";

        public NormAdapterDiscriminatorConvention() : base(elementName) { }

        public override BsonValue GetDiscriminator(Type nominalType, Type actualType)
        {
            var type = string.Format("{0}, {1}", actualType.FullName, actualType.Assembly.GetName().Name);
            return type;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are using Interfaces and the converter clearly doesn't know which class it should use create this object inside application. Check how does the data look in DB (if it has some type information) and check information what you could provide to your Convert to be able to handle this. E.g. this [mapping](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/reference/bson/mapping/) could help you with that.

Comment: Why don't you let us help you fix your discriminator convention? That seems like the better option here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Tatranskymedved I'll read your docs right now

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I just added the discriminators

Comment: My guess is that `StandardDiscriminatorConvention` is looking up `MyDiscriminator` and then calling it.

Comment: It is calling it, but in an ifninite loop. I'm trying to figure out why, but it looks really complicated. That's why I'm looking for an alternative